# Naive method of limit evaluation

Tags: limits

Suppose for simplicity that I have:

$$\lim_{r\to 1} x_{1}(r) = \lim_{r \to 1} x_{2}(r) = c$$

Now consider the function

$$f(x_{1},x_{2}) = [x_{1}^{r} + x_{2}^{r}]^{\frac{1}{r}}$$

and the limit:

$$\lim_{r \to 1} f(x_{1}(r),x_{2}(r))=\lim_{r \to 1} [x_{1}(r)^{r} + x_{2}(r)^{r}]^{\frac{1}{r}} $$

The temptation (at least for me) is to evaluate the limit in a naive way as:

$$\lim_{r \to 1} f(x_{1}(r),x_{2}(r))=\lim_{r \to 1} [x_{1}(r)^{r} + x_{2}(r)^{r}]^{\frac{1}{r}} = \lim_{m\to 1} \lim_{r\to 1} [x_{1}(r)^{m} + x_{2}(r)^{m}]^{\frac{1}{m}} = 2c $$

I am wondering under what conditions of the function $f$ is this naive method of limit evaluation valid?

While this limit above is obviously very simple, it can be made more complex by taking $r \to 0$ or $r \to -\infty$, where using this "sequential" method becomes much more useful.

Comment: I can't understand: your function $f$ is given, so how can you impose conditions?

Comment: This is just a motivating example. If I was given another function I want to know what conditions that function must satisfy for this method to give the correct limit. However I dont even know if this method is technically valid for this example (although it does give the correct limit). I want to know if the function needs to be continuous, monotonic, concave etc. etc. for me to apply this method. Let me know if it is still not clear

Comment: You basically need the continuity of $f$ as a function of two variables... Anyway, for a general $f$ there is no natural way to introduce an artificial limit as $m \to 1$.